# Laravel Migrations - Column already exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am running `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45` and want to migrate my database migrations.

I have two migrations. One is the standard `2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table` that comes out of the box and the other one is my newly created migration `2017_02_19_172350_create_keywords_table`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateKeywordsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('keywords', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('keyword');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamps('published_at');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('keywords');
    }
}
```

Doing the typical `php artisan migrate` I get(before rolling back):

```
root:~/workspace $ php artisan migrate:rollback
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
root:~/workspace $ php artisan migrate


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at' (SQL: create table `keywords` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr  
  ement primary key, `keyword` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated  
  _at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)                                                                             



  [PDOException]                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at'  


root:~/workspace $
```

Inside the database no table `keywords` is created.

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Try **composer dump** command and then try **php aristan migration:refresh**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$table->timestamps();` is a function that always will add the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. In your case, you are adding these twice.
If you want to add another timestamp field, you have to use the `timestamp()` function.

So you should replace the line for `published_at` with the following (remove the s):

```
$table->timestamp('published_at');
```

A list of all possible column types can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns).